# How to do the best lookup textfield for JAVA Swing

Tags: java, swing

How to do the best lookup textfield for JAVA Swing like below:

[image]

Comment: Start by taking a look at the auto complete support in SwingX.  If that doesn't meet your needs, you'll have to start by writing some code based on your needs/requirements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually not very easy to achieve, not if you want a flexible and re-usable solution at the end of the process.

You need a `JTextField` (well, okay, that was obvious), a `JList` and a `JPopupMenu` or `JWindow`.

You need some kind of filtering mechanism that can take a `String` and produce a `List` of matches, which can then be displayed within the `JList`.  This will require you to provide a `ListCellRenderer` for you particular implementation.

You will need to attach a `DocumentListener` to the `JTextField`.  When the document is updated/changed, you will need to pass the text of the text field to your filtering engine to find all the possible matches and display them within the `JList`.

If the popup is not visible, you will need to make it visible, taking into account that the list might not fit on the screen based on where the text field is.  If it is visible, you may need to re-pack the window to better accomidate the available options (if any)

If the user leaves the field, you will need to decide if you want to auto complete the text based on the first match, invalid the field or leave the text as is and close the popup if it's visible.

If the user clicks on a value, you will need to extract the `String` representation of the item and apply it to the text field and close the popup.

You will need to add key bindings to the text field to accommodate the <kbd>down arrow</kbd> which could open the popup window and/or move to the first item in the list.  This will trigger a lose of focus, so you need to be prepared for it.

You will probably also want to provide a <kbd>Escape</kbd> keyboard binding for the popup/field so the user can dismiss the popup